# Does Facebook have a list of icons that others can use?

Tags: facebook, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook official icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848719/facebook-official-icons)

For Facebook's 16x16 pixel icon, the following url is used fairly a lot, but this isn't stated by Facebook that people can use this, is it?

http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/icons/favicon.gif

Is there any official list of icons from Facebook that people can use their own site for Facebook Connect?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Facebook promotional guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/pages/manage/promo_guidelines.php) and the official "sharing" [widgets](http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/index.php).