# Facebook official icons

Tags: facebook, user-interface, icons

I'm going to develop apps for iOS, Android and Windows Phone that will be connect with Facebook.

I'm searching http://developer.facebook.com but I haven't found official icons for login button, etc. Sometime ago I'm sure they were there, but now I can't find them.

Where I can get official facebook icons?

iOS SDK comes with a FBConnect.bundle but I don't know how to open that file and get its images to use them on the other platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Facebook Brand Resources](https://www.facebookbrand.com/) is the place to get official graphics and how you can use it.

You need to use either self-made/custom images or one of the Facebook logos from <strike>["Brand Permissions Center"](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php)</strike> [Facebook Brand Assets](https://www.facebookbrand.com/).